# How to deploy maven jar in different environments?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, jar

I have a standalone application which generates jar through maven.It does not have any ear or war.the jar file gets generated in my target folder.I want to understand the build deploy process for this jar file.suppose I want to deploy this jar file in 10 different environments.How to do it.shall i directly copy jar from eclipse or shall i copy it from tortoise svn.How does artifact get generated in different environment.I will be copying jar file to winscp and deploying it through putty in all different environment.please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the jar file manually to each machine, you do the following:
a. Store your app jar file in a maven repository.
Refer link for instructions: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html
b. On the machines where you wish to execute the you can use maven to execute the application.
http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I am not copying jar instantly to all environments.Its situational.suppose today i want to deploy in one environment nad tomorrow on 10th env?I should copy my local jar file to folder in desired environment by win scp.is it?

Comment: This is a good answer, and if you rule these environments, you _should_ install Maven on each one of them, and run `mvn install` on demand wherever you want to upgrade. Look out: If you copy your jar file manually, you must copy all of its dependencies along. That's what Maven was created for! For saving you troubles managing and handling dependencies.